# IBOutlet declaration place

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

After searching on Google about this confusion, I [found out](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/#iboutlet) that the best place to put an `IBOutlet` is:

```
@interface GallantViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch;

@end
```

but from what I say, now the `switch` variable is visible outside of the `GallantViewController`. Isn't that odd? I thought that this wrong method:

```
@interface GoofusViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UISwitch *_switch
}

@end
```

was behaving like this, and moving it would fix it. Why would you want to manipulate a button for example from another class instead of implementing it's logic just in the `GallantViewController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@interface` can appear in both the `.h` file (public properties) and the `.m` file (private properties). The `IBOutlets` should be declared in the `.m` file.

For example, here's a sample `.m` file for a view controller

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
// the following property is not visible outside this file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *someView;  
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Technically, the `@interface` in the `.m` file is a class extension (also known as an anonymous category on the class), but that's of no practical interest. It's just a way to add private properties to the class.

Comment: But still, the example in the article I linked to is declaring them in the `.h` file, right?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei I didn't read the article, all of my information comes from the Apple docs, and the Stanford CS193P lectures. You can declare `IBOutlets` in the `.h`, but that makes them public.